# Angular 2 iframe confusion

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe

I am attempting to change the value of an element inside of an iframe in Angular 2. I have tried many things, but am continuously unable to reference an item using `getElementById()`. I have a test scenario which works in one case, and not another, which is serving to confuse me even further:

### component.html

```
<iframe #iframe src="assets/test.html"></iframe>
```

### test.html

```
<h1 id="wow">Wow</h1>
```

### working typescript (prints `<h1 id="wow">Wow<h1>`)

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument;
        doc.open();
        doc.write('<h1 id="wow">Wow</h1>');
        doc.close();
        console.log(doc.getElementById("wow"));
    }
}
```

### non-working typescript (prints `null`)

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument;
        console.log(doc.getElementById("wow"));
    }
}
```

### Question

How in the world can I get the second one to properly print the element? No matter what I do or what I put in `test.html`, it is always null.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside `ngAfterViewInit()`, it's likely that test.html hasn't been loaded into `iframe` yet.

This can be subverted using the `(load)="yourLoadFunction()"` directive on your `iframe` like `<iframe (load)="yourLoadFunction()"></iframe>`

If you then move the code from `ngAfterViewInit()` into `yourLoadFunction()`, it should work correctly.

Comment: Hey Hikmat, this ended up being exactly what was going on, which was surprising because I thought that was exactly what ngAfterViewInit was supposed to be there for.. What I ended up doing on the iframe was `load)=onLoad()` and changed the `ngAfterViewInit()` call to `onLoad()`. If you want to add some information to your answer I will happily accept, but as it stands there's not quite enough detail

Comment: Actually I am new to Angular 2, so don't know much about it.I tried to give a hint, and I am glad if it helped you.

Comment: Ahh, good instinct then! When I get a chance I'll edit your answer to help the next person a bit more, then accept

Comment: Hi @JaronThatcher, Hikmat. This is working great for me in Chrome, but IE (as per usual) has problems: The `doc.close()` fires off the `(load)` event again... recursively. I haven't worked out how to unsubscribe from `(load)` in the handler, but skipping the `doc.close()` seems to work. Flagging the iframe to skip content loading the second time through hasn't worked, yet, either.

Comment: May this could help : Pass the event object to the load handler `(load)="yourLoadFunction($event)"` and in your `yourLoadFunction` do this : `event.target.removeListener('load')`